# Simple JS menu toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am pretty new to JavaScript and decided to code a menu that opens/expands when you click a button and closes when you click the button again.

I got everything to work but I cannot seem to find why the menu isn't closing.

Here is my code:

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!
I have included my HTML, CSS and JS files.

```js
let toggleNavStatus = false;

let toggleNav = function (){
    let getSideBar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
    let getSideBarUl = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar ul");
    let getSideBarUTitle = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");
    let getSideBarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-sidebar a");

    if(toggleNavStatus === false){
        getSideBarUl.style.visibility = "visible"; 
        getSideBar.style.width = "295px";    
        getSideBarTitle.style.opacity = "0.5";

        let arrayLenght = getSideBarLinks.length;
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++){
            getSideBarLinks[i].style.opacity = "1";
        }
        toggleNavStatus = true;
  } else if(toggleNavStatus === true){
    getSideBarUl.style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    getSideBar.style.width = "50px";    
    getSideBarTitle.style.opacity = "0";

    let arrayLenght = getSideBarLinks.length;
    for(let i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++){
        getSideBarLinks[i].style.opacity = "0";
    }
    toggleNavStatus = false;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.nav-main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.btn-toggle-nav{
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f98f39;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle-nav:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav-main ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.nav-main ul li{
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.nav-main ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
 .nav-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    z-index: 1000;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul{
    padding-top: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li{
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li span, ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #222;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ZiGi's Toggle Menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resetstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="nav-main"> 

        <div class="btn-toggle-nav" onclick="toggleNav()"></div>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> About Us</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Gallery</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <aside class="nav-sidebar"> 
        <ul>
            <li> <span>Projects</span></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Making a Website </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> SEAO Optimizing Video </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Walking Through The Park </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Just Another Day</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </aside>

</body>
<script src="main.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: Provide a what?

Comment: Go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and paste your HTML, CSS, and JS there. it will generate a link for you. paste that link here so anyone can see your whole code of menu and debug that for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/21z95jqh/ here you go

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/60200467/7785337

Comment: @SabirHussain One is required to post a [mcve] here, within the question, and not a third party site. Doing so might get this question closed.

Comment: @Rob I have edited my post and fixed it.

Comment: You have defined `getSideBarUTitle` but in places you are using `getSideBarTitle`

Comment: @NiK648 Yess! Just found the bug and thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I have posted an answer for you. if it works vote up and mark it correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an `HTML/CSS` issue than it is `JavaScript`. `CSS` comes with a `:hover` selector that activates any styling presets made on that element. You can group this up with your classes to all work in sync with each other at the same time.

Give this a try!

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.

In my JS file, on line 12 there is a typo when assigning the variable.

`let getSideBarUTitle = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");`

should be

`let getSideBarTitle = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that for you but it is just a basic show hide with JavaScript.You can extend it anytime to get a proper transition.

Note: JavaScript script is at the bottom of HTML not is the JS section.

Solution:

```css
body {
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

.nav-main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.btn-toggle-nav{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f98f39;
    background-size: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle-nav:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav-main ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 60px;
}

.nav-main ul li{
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.nav-main ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
}
 .nav-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    z-index: 1000;
    
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul{
    padding-top: 15px;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li{
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li span, ul li a{
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .nav-sidebar ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #222;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ZiGi's Toggle Menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resetstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="nav-main"> 

        <button class="btn-toggle-nav" onclick="toggleNav()">nav</button>

        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Home</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Portfolio</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> About Us</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Gallery</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <aside class="nav-sidebar" id="nav-sidebar" 
    style="display:none"> 
        <ul>
            <li> <span>Projects</span></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Making a Website </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> SEAO Optimizing Video </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Walking Through The Park </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Just Another Day</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </aside>

</body>
<script>
function toggleNav(){
 console.log("Hello");
  var x = document.getElementById("nav-sidebar");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```