# JS navslide function not working on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

im not much of a coder but this code has worked for many people and I've spent hours trying to find my error. when I click the hamburger menu the slide menu off to the right is supposed to slide into view and fade the buttons in from opacity 0 to opacity 1. none of this happens at all which makes me think I have a js error.

any help would be great.

jsfiddle below

```js
const navSlide = () => {
 const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
 const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links')
 
 burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
   nav.classlist.toggle('nav-active');
 });
}

navSlide();
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,200,400,600,700,900&display=swap');
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header {
 height: 2.5em;
 background-color:#7BC58A;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 text-align: left;
 padding-left: 6em;
 padding-top: .4em;
 
 
}

.logo-image{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0em;
 
}

nav{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 8vh;
 
}

.nav-links{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width:45%;
 
}

.nav-links li{
 list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
 color:#5A5A5A; 
 font-size:.75em; 
 text-transform:uppercase; 
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; 
 font-weight:600;
}

.nav-links a:hover{
 color:#7BC58A;
}

.nav-links a:active {
 color: #D1D1D1;
}

.burger{
 display: none;
 float:right;
 position: relative;
 top:0px;
}

.burger div{
 width:25px;
 height:3px;
 background-color:#5a5a5a;
 margin: 3px;
 border-radius: 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
 .nav-links{
  width:55%;
 }
}


@media screen and (max-width:768px){
 body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 .nav-links{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  height:92vh;
  top: 8vh;
  background-color: #7BC58A;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  transform: translate(100%);
  
 }
 
 .nav-links li{
  opacity:1;
 }
 
 .burger{
  display:block;
 }
}
.nav-active{
  transform:translatex(100%)
 }
 
 @keyframes navLinksFade{
  from{
   opacity:0;
   transform:translateX(50px);
  }
  to{
   opacity:1;
   transform:translateX(0px);
  }
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 
</head>

<body>
 <section class="header">
  
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (209)838-1934 <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> inquiry@allseasonlawn.net
 </section>
 
 
<!-- NAVIGATION STARTS-->
 
 <nav id="nav">
  
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <div class="logo-image">
            <img src="images/navbar_logo_50x50.png" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
</a>
  
 
  <ul class="nav-links">
  <li><a href="/index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
 
  
  
  <li><a href="/reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
  <li><a href="/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
   
  </div>
   </nav>
 
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/robertrlamb96/3yuzok8r/1/

Comment: Refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60200467/7785337

Answer (score 0):

You had two problems with adding the class. First was you were trying to attach the event listener before the browser has parsed (read) the full html. In other words, the browser didn't know what "burger" or "nav" referred to. To overcome this you need to run the script as part of an onload method. Note, in JSFiddle you have to set the Load type to "no wrap bottom of " to have access to this and I do not believe SO snippets support this feature.

The second error was that "class**L**ist" was misspelled (the 'l' is capitalized). I believe you still have some work to do to get it working, but this gets the script running.

```
const navSlide = () => {
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links')

burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
});
}

onload = ()=>{
    navSlide();
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6qj0kwmg/